# Is this a special adapter used on angle grinders in order to use them for polishing?

Tags: tools

I have this small angle grinder and I want to use it for beveling tiles that I am going to install.

The process also requires some polishing of the bigger than 45 degrees cuts and they use a polishing tool like below. That looks like an angle grinder with some adapter installed. What is the name for it?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a sanding disk for peel and stick sanding disks.  The guard is just removed for the picture, right?

Comment: or it could be a scotchbrite pad on there,

Comment: Note that I've only ever seen these sold from Chinese or other "off shore" sellers.  Its not something you can buy at the hardware store - I think there must be some safety regulations that keep others from selling them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Product search terms:

- [Angle grinder polishing disk](https://www.google.com/search?q=angle%20grinder%20polishing%20disk&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjr5cyHhcryAhUQvKwKHSZyAPYQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=angle%20grinder%20polishing%20disk&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIGCAAQChAYOgQIIxAnOgQIABBDOgUIABCABDoICAAQgAQQsQM6BwgAELEDEEM6BggAEAgQHjoECAAQGDoECAAQHlCYYVjAggFgr4sBaABwAHgBgAGgBogBjiiSAQwwLjIyLjIuNS0xLjGYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=AxklYavYNJD4sgWm5IGwDw&bih=907&biw=1680&rlz=1C1ZCEB_enUS850US850)
- [Angle grinder buffing wheel](https://www.google.com/search?q=angle%20grinder%20buffing%20wheel&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwid1sKRhcryAhWWYqwKHbauAV8Q2-cCegQIABAA&oq=angle%20grinder%20buffing%20wheel&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIECAAQGDIECAAQGDIECAAQGDoGCAAQCBAeOgQIABAeUJG6AVjrxwFgrckBaABwAHgBgAGqAogB-g2SAQYwLjExLjGYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=GBklYZ3qKJbFsQW23Yb4BQ&bih=907&biw=1680&rlz=1C1ZCEB_enUS850US850)

Angle grinders have a threaded output shaft, so the one in your photo probably just screws on.